# Can JavaScript talk to Selenium 2?

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know I can get Selenium 2's webdriver to run JavaScript and get return values but so much asynchronous stuff is happening I would like JavaScript to talk to Selenium instead of the other way around. I have done some searching and haven't found anything like this. Do people just generally use `implicitly_wait`? That seems likely to fail since it's not possible to time everything? Perfect example would be to let Selenium know when an XHR completed or an asynchronous animation with undetermined execution time.

Is this possible? We're using Selenium 2 with Python on Saucelabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look into the execute_async_script() method (JavascriptExecutor.executeAsyncScript in Java, IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteAsyncScript() in .NET), which allows you to wait for a callback function. The callback function is automatically appended to the `arguments` array in your JavaScript function. So, assuming you have a JavaScript function already on the page that waits until the condition you want, you could do something like the following (Java code below, C# and Python code should be similar):

```
String script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"
    + "callback(myJavaScriptFunctionThatWaitsUntilReady());";

driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(script);
```

It might be possible to be even more clever and pass the callback function directly to an event that returns the proper data. You can find more information on the executeAsyncScript() function in the project [JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html), and can find sample code for this in the project source tree. There's a great example of waiting for an XHR to complete in the tests in [this file](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/ExecutingAsyncJavascriptTest.java).

If this isn't yet available in the version of the Python bindings available for use with SauceLabs, I would expect it to be available before long. Admittedly, in a sense, this is pushing the "poll for desired state" from your test case into JavaScript, but it would make your test more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically it is possible, but I would advise against it.

The solution would probably have some jQuery running on the site that sets a variable to true when the JavaScript processing has finished.

Set selenium up to loop through a getEval until this variable becomes true and then do something in Selenium.

It would meet your requirements but it's a really bad idea.  If for some reason your jQuery doesn't set the trigger variable to true (or whatever state you expect) Selenium will sit there indefinetly.  You could put a really long timeout on it, but then what would be the different in just getting Selenium to do a getEval and wait for a specific element to appear?

It sounds like you are trying to overengineer your solution and it will cause you more pain in the future will very few additional benefits.

Comment: You're suggesting polling with Selenium which isn't the same thing. I was wondering if Selenium had any hooks it listened to that it added to the site. I am amazed it doesn't. Even Flash has this in flash externals.

Comment: Selenium doesn't modify the site, it just looks at the DOM and the HTML.  The only way you could do what you want to do is by manipulating the DOM somehow and then getting Selenium to check the DOM for your change.  You can't drive selenium from your website.

Comment: You can't drive selenium from your website. That's my answer then. It should do this in my opinion, but doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not to be overly blunt, but if you want your App to talk to your Test Runner, then you're doing it wrong.

If you need to wait for an XHR to finish, you could try displaying a spinner and then test that the spinner has disappeared to indicate a successful request.

In regards to the animation, when the animation has completed, maybe its callback could add a class indicating that the animation has finished and then you could test for the existence of that class.

Comment: In both cases you are ignoring the timing portion. JavaScript is asynchronous. I'm not asking how to have Selenium check things, I'm asking how to tell when to check. A question you haven't answered. Since JavaScript is asynchronous the best time is when JavaScript is ready and only JavaScript knows when that is. A hook is the best way to do it. So are there any?

Comment: In my experience with Selenium 1 and 2, your test triggers an asynchronous call in your app. Then you use a wait_for command to wait for an element to exist (or not exist). If you write your app to expect Selenium to exist, then I think you are approaching the problem incorrectly. Your app shouldn't care about Selenium, or any other testing framework for that matter. That allows you to swap out test runners in the future if anything better comes out.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better answer: You tell Selenium to check immediately after triggering an asynchronous action. Selenium will then wait for a period of time for that condition to exist. If it doesn't exist within the time allotted, then it is assumed that the action failed so the test should fail.

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality.  My idea would be to have the javascript raise an event when it is done, and listen to such event in selenium, possibly through a javascript started by webdriver.  As my experience with javascript is limited, I'm not sure this is feasible.  The event mechanism would avoid the hard dependency issue, but it would of course require the original javascript to provide the event which could mean changing the code.

Comment: @oif_vet asynchronous function calls like xmlhttprequests return immediately... The effects are asynchronous, you supply callbacks which are called at a later time. Selenium will not wait. JavaScript needs to tell Selenium when it's ready.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding me. I understand that the script is executing and returning immediately. What you need to test for is a visual indicator that the asynchronous request has completed. This is usually done by displaying a spinner graphic that indicates to the user that something is happening. In Selenium, you would test that the spinner is no longer visible.

Comment: Check out the docs: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/index.html and click on "Method List" and search for "wait". You will see several different methods that will tell Selenium what to wait for (including wait_for_ajax, though I have had issues with that personally)

Comment: No you do not understand me. I do not have a problem figuring out if script failed or not. I have trouble figuring out when to check.

Comment: @apphacker No I think you are the one who is not understanding - the answer is that you cannot tell Selenium when to check; it will check straight away. What you can do though is put something in before hand that it can check until it is time to test for success in what you're really interested in. Providing a visual prompt to your user would be the best way to do this, as it also helps your user see that the website is doing something. Your visual prompt is controlled by your javascript, performing the function you wanted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what both of you are saying and that both of you are simply skipping over the "how to know when to check" which is what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Testing animation with selenium is opening a can of worms. The tests can be quite brittle and cause many false positives.

The problem is to do that the calls are asynchronous, and difficult to track the behaviour and change in state of the page.

In my experience the asynchronous call can be so quick that the spinner is never displayed, and the state of the page may skip a state entirely (that Selenium can detect).

Waiting for the state of the page to transition can make the tests less brittle, however the false positives cannot be removed entirely.

I recommend manual testing for animation.